# Import and connect Outlook Calendar in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I want to create a winforms application that should show the calendar of an Outlook user and allow me to modify it (create events,..).

My end goal will be that I have all Outlook calendars of my colleagues (5) in a simple GUI.

I haven't found much documentation about this so I was wondering: is this even possible?

Are there API's or other documentation that could help me commence?

Comment: what is your calendaring provider?  Exchange?

Comment: Yes i'm sorry, it's an Hosted Exchange Server. Keep in mind that I already do have access to the calendars in my outlook. What I want to realize is the same lay out but in a C# winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using Exchange Web Services if on-premise hosting or Microsoft Graph with hosting in the cloud.

on-prem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange

graph / REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/